# setting up linux cron jobs from java

Tags: java, cron, schedule

I want to be able to setup linux cron jobs from a java program.

I know to setup a cron job, i use the crontab tool:

```
crontab -e
```

and then specify the cron expressions.

How do i do this programmatically from a java program?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a ProcessBuilder?

Answer (score 1):

You can (assuming you have permission) directly modify your crontab file using Java's many file I/O functions. The file can (at least on my system) be found at:

```
/var/spool/cron/crontabs/paxdiablo
```

(for the user `paxdiablo`). Simply make whatever changes you want to this file and then send a HUP signal to the `cron` daemon.

However, directly editing that file is frowned upon and indeed it may well be protected from you.

To do it *properly,* you can use the `crontab -l` command to capture the current contents to a file (eg, `me.cron`). The `crontab -l` command writes your crontab file to standard output, unlike `crontab -e` which tries to bring it up in an editor.

Then you can use whatever means you wnt to modify *that* file (it's yours because you created it).

Then, running `crontab me.cron` will install that file (with any changes you've made) and notify `cron` so that it re-reads it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
String cmd = "crontab -e";
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "/c" , cmd);
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = builder.start();
```

Comment: Why redirect error stream? If i could write to the outputstream of the process, and then write to it?